# Which are mutually exclusive:Bit fields or formatting flags? In c++

Tags: c++, flags, bit-fields

I was reading about formatting flags and the groups which they belongs to ( called bitfields) and a statement reads that:-

> there are three bit fields and each has a group of format flags which are mutually exclusive

So my question is the term " mutually exclusive " is for format flags or bitfields? and what is its meaning actually?
Thanks!

Comment: From the sentence structure, it is the "format flags" that are mutually exclusive.   If two or more flags are mutually exclusive it means that only one can be set (e.g. to true) at a time   i.e.  if any one flag is set, that excludes the possibility of setting any of the others.

Comment: So according to this meaning of  "mutually exclusive" , format flags within one bit field are mutually exclusive because we cannot set more than one flag from one bit field at the same time. 

Thanks for commenting @peter

Comment: without context, it's impossible to say whether the statement is correct or not.    I was describing what the words say, by normal rules of english expression.     It depends on how the bitfields are used - what the meaning of each combination of bits has for a given library/program/whatever.   For example, if a bitfield can represent three values which - to the code doing the formatting - represent decimal, octal, and hexadecimal output, then those three values are mutually exclusive (doing decimal output means not doing hexadecimal output at the same time, and vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term means that if you have a set of conditions or states (the implementation isn't important) then only one of them can be 'true' or set at any one time.

Comment: The claim that it's an oxymoron based on a spurious meaning of 'mutually' doesn't help.

Comment: That's the definition of 'mutuality', which is a different word, and even then I'd disagree that that meaning contracts the meaning of exclusive (presumably you also think that 'exclusive relationship' is an oxymoron, or 'blue green'). If you want to argue about the dictionary definitions, ask a question on https://english.stackexchange.com/ instead. The non-technical definition has no value when answering this question and only serves to confuse.

Comment: A dictionary definition of "mutually"  (not mutuality) that is relevant here "having the same relationship toward each other".    With that definition, saying "A and B are mutually exclusive" means "A excludes B and B also excludes A" - i.e. they can't both be true at the same time.   More generally, saying "members of a set of possibilities are mutually exclusive" means that "if any possibility in the set is true, all of the others are not".       So I agree with Pete Kirkham's position - this answer is ridiculous.

Comment: What was intended as a light-hearted introduction (and was as told to me in 1981 by my then professor of computer science) has got completely out-of-hand. I have better things to do than read all this. I'll edit my answer and remove the offending material. I hope everyone's day gets better as a result.